# Camera.Parameters.getHorizontalViewAngle() throwing NullPointerExceptions

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Camera cam=Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters pa=cam.getParameters();
float f=pa.getHorizontalViewAngle(); //Returning null value
..........
}
```

Why is a null value being returned?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 things:

1. The camera is still closed; check if the value of camera parameters is null.
2. The horizontal view angle is not set on your device; try with an another device.